# GCM: Android widgets. Generate token based on WidgetID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-widget

I am newbie to Android Application development and was wondering if someone can help me figure out a problem.

I am creating a widget which is of the following form
[    Text View   ] [ + ] [ - ]

The text View displays a number which is increased by pressing the + button and decreased by pressing the - button.

The Plus and Minus buttons interact with my server which sends back a count value which is displayed in the text view.

This widget can be installed on multiple android phones and at all times the count should be latest.

To accomplish this, I have integrated Google Cloud messaging to send a push notification with a count value to all registered widgets.

Everything is working fine when the widget is installed on different phones.

However, if I install two widgets on the same phone the token I am receiving from Google is the same. The relevant code attached

```
 try {
        tokenPerWidgetId.put(appWidgetId, instanceId.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
             GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null));
        Log.v("RegisterationToken", registerToken);
      } catch (IOException ie) {
        Log.v("RegisterationToken", "Failed");
        setViewsOnError(views, " Could not register with Google.  Please re-install");
                }
```

I understand why it's happening as according to Google Docs, getToken first time gets the token from the Server and other times return the token.

However, how do I generate a token based on AppWidgetId?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried creating widgets, but with GCM you'll have to have 2 registration tokens for each widget. If you'll be able to call the [`instanceId.getToken`](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) when the widget is created, and store them separately it looks like it can work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. However, I am confused with Instance ID and Token. Looks like google handles Instance ID and I am getting same token when the widget is installed on the same mobile. let me check it out.

Comment: I just tested and printed the instance ID. On the same mobile, calling this API, InstanceID instanceId = InstanceID.getInstance(this); gives me the same Instance ID and therefore the same token